# How a Leave one out Cross Validation model gets tested on real world data

Tags: logistic, classification, python, cross-validation

I am using this leave-one-out Cross validation model in order to judge my model. However, I have multiple questions on this topic.

1. We are training model for all remaining samples and then testing on 1. What do we do when a real world data comes. Do we train the model again for the real world data?
2. If we are training the model for all sample except one, then do we tune the model every time for each sample. This seems to be very tedious task when you actually deploy model to outside world.
3. How do you choose a final model if you do not want to train a model for real world data.

The data set which I have is a healthcare classification problem which has very low sample (450) set provided. It is asked us to provide the evaluation using LOOCV. But I am not able to understand the real world usage for this.